# Keyboard shortcut to rename file from within app

Tags: macos, keyboard

I want to be able to rename a document on apple applications (Pages, Logic, and TextEdit specifically) from within the application itself. <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> activates "Save as", but this duplicates the document and then renames the duplicate, leaving the original with the same name.

Is there a common keyboard shortcut to rename a document without duplicating it?

Comment: Do you *need* this to be a key command, or is mouse OK?

Comment: Yes, this is primarily just for workflow efficiency, I am aware of the conventional way to rename a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a keyboard command to any menu item, either per app or globally.

[image]

System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts

Click + to add a shortcut.
Type the *exact* menu name, being careful with the ellipsis … which is not the same thing as three stops/periods. You can generate this with  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>;</kbd>  [semicolon] on English layouts.
Make sure your command won't conflict with anything else - I didn't actually test if this one would conflict, just to show as an example.

[image]

This will then be reflected in the menu itself.

[image]

For sake of completeness, you can also rename by mouse-click on the name at the top of the document, which will change in the Finder.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I've used this feature lots before, don't know why I didn't think of it

Comment: Possibly because in this case you don't really expect there to be a menu item for Rename - it's not really a common menu item other than in Apple's 'magic save' apps.